# fork: close all open sockets

Tags: python, unix, fork, multiprocessing

I am using `multiprocessing.Pool.map`, which forks the current process.

My understanding is that by default, all file descriptors **including sockets** are copied from the master process when forking. The master process itself is a web server (using [cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org/)), so this wreaks havoc with open ports etc. The forked processes are really only doing some [CPU-heavy numerical stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964809/numpy-vs-multiprocessing-and-mmap) inside one of the libraries that the server is using -- nothing to do with the web/socket part.

Is there an easy way to automatically close all sockets in the new processes? Or another way to avoid issues with forking a CherryPy server?

Using CherryPy 3.2.2, Python 2.7; must work on Linux and OS X.

Comment: The lazy way is to create the process pool before opening any sockets.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a "current" snapshot of all memory, at `pool.map()` invocation time... just not the sockets :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIX does not include a sensible way to list or close a range of file descriptors.

So we have to loop over the full range (like from 3 to 1023), closing the file descriptors one at a time.

Or, if we have a /proc file system, we can read the list of open file descriptors in /proc/self/fd and close just those.  This can be quicker than closing all possible file descriptors.

```
import os

def close_files(fd_min=3, fd_max=-1):
    if os.path.exists('/proc/self/fd'):
        close_files_with_procfs(fd_min, fd_max)
    else:
        close_files_exhaustively(fd_min, fd_max)

def close_files_exhaustively(fd_min=3, fd_max=-1):
    import resource
    fd_top = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)[1] - 1
    if fd_max == -1 or fd_max > fd_top:
        fd_max = fd_top
    for fd in range(fd_min, fd_max+1):
        try:
            os.close(fd)
        except OSError:
            pass

def close_files_with_procfs(fd_min=3, fd_max=-1):
    for nm in os.listdir("/proc/self/fd"):
        if nm.startswith('.'):
            continue
        fd = int(nm)
        if fd >= fd_min and (fd_max == -1 or fd < fd_max):
            try:
                os.close(fd)
            except OSError:
                pass

def timereps(reps, func):
    from time import time
    start = time()
    for i in range(0, reps):
        func()
    end = time()
    return (end - start) / reps

print "close_files: %f" % timereps(100, lambda: close_files())
print "close_files_exhaustively: %f" % timereps(100, lambda: close_files_exhaustively())
print "close_files_with_procfs: %f" % timereps(1000, lambda: close_files_with_procfs())
```

On my system:

```
$ python ./close_fds.py 
close_files: 0.000094
close_files_exhaustively: 0.010151
close_files_with_procfs: 0.000039
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to use the [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) library to list all the connections open by the current process. The following will close all connections, though you may want to filter those of interest:

```
import psutil, os

p = psutil.Process()
for c in p.connections(kind='inet'):
   os.close(c.fd)
```