# Change y log scale imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot spectrogram with y-scale depending on the period, so I want to have a reversed log-scale.

The thing is: I found how to do it using `pcolormesh()`, not by using `imshow()`. `imshow()` seems to be more efficient than `pcolormesh()`, that is, for me, a great reason to prefer it !

Did I miss something ?

I do not know how to say more clearly so here is a reproducible example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

size = 10
data = np.arange(size * size).reshape((size, size))

x_start = 1
x_end = 10
y_start = 1
y_end = 10

extent = [x_start, x_end, y_start, y_end]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,4)

axes[0].set_yscale('log')
im = axes[0].imshow(data, extent=extent, origin='upper', interpolation='None', cmap='viridis')


axes[1].set_yscale('log')
im2 = axes[1].imshow(data, extent=extent, origin='lower', interpolation='None', cmap='viridis')

axes[2].set_yscale('log')
im2 = axes[2].imshow(data, extent=extent, origin='lower', interpolation='None', cmap='viridis')
axes[2].invert_yaxis()

y = np.arange(1,11)*0.1
x = np.arange(0,10)
axes[3].set_yscale('log')
im3 = axes[3].pcolormesh(x, 1/y , data)

axes[0].set_title("not ok")
axes[1].set_title("not ok")
axes[2].set_title("not ok")
axes[3].set_title("OK")

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

You see on the previous image that tight ordinates do not change using `imshow()`, they are always on the top of the figure even if I use `lower` or `upper` `origin`. With `pcolormesh()`, I achieved to get tight ordinates on the bottom of the graph.

I would dream to get the "ok" figure by using `imshow()` !

This question is relative to this one: [Aggregate several AxesSubplot after multiprocessing to draw a matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57269797/aggregate-several-axessubplot-after-multiprocessing-to-draw-a-matplotlib-figure)

Comment: might be worth saying this is a follow on question from https://stackoverflow.com/q/57269797/1358308

Comment: also, how big is the data you want to work with?  i.e. what is `data.shape` for some data you actually want to plot?

Comment: shape: (2048,15357)

Comment: OK, so resampling this down to something more sensible in the process would probably be a good idea.  if that can get down to approx (500,500) before matplotlib sees it things will be much faster

Comment: The optimization question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57269797/aggregate-several-axessubplot-after-multiprocessing-to-draw-a-matplotlib-figure, let's try to keep the comments in the correct thread

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to get?

```
axes[1].set_yscale('log')
im2 = axes[1].imshow(data, extent=extent, origin='lower', interpolation='None', cmap='viridis')
axes[1].invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for trying ! sadly, invert-yaxis() is not enough: it reverts the y legends too, that I do not want ... I update my question now

Comment: I think this is not possible with `imshow`. Possibly [`NonUniformImage`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.NonUniformImage) would help.