# Python multiprocessing shared list not getting written to

Tags: python, multithreading, list

I have a certain class that has an attribute list. There are some functions in the class that write to, but never read from this list. I initialize the class with a list and call the functions from multiple threads, however after waiting for all threads to finish the list remains empty.

The value order in the list does not matter.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

class TestClass():

    def __init__(self, vals):
        self.vals = vals
        
    def linearrun(self):
        Is = range(2000)
        Js = range(2000)
        
        for i in Is:
            for j in Js:
                self.vals.append(i+j)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vals = []
    instantiated_class = TestClass(vals)
    processes = []

    for _ in range(10):
        new_process=Process(target=instantiated_class.linearrun)
        processes.append(new_process)
        new_process.start()
    
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print(vals)
```

Comment: whenever you spawn a new process, python copies the objects needed to run the function, in your case the 10 process you are creating creates 10 copies of each `instantiated_class` and the list attribute `self.vals`

Comment: might want to look into https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues if you want to communicate between processes

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful to know. Do pipes work for parent-child connection as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721915/shared-memory-objects-in-multiprocessing or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857838/modify-object-in-python-multiprocessing seems to be a good start

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for your help @python_user!