# Updating a numpy array using multiprocessing module

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a simple Jaccard like similarity calculation on a list of n-gram sets as shown below. This code executes fine using a relatively smaller list, yet memory usage starts becoming a concern when the list size get larger, say 10k or more. Instead of appending results in a list, if I can populate a Numpy zero-allocated array within the similarity calculation function, it seems this memory issue could be eliminated.

What would be the best way to do get results in an array? Thanks.

```
def myfunc3(idx):
    mylist = []
    for jj in range(idx+1,len_lines):
        aa = setng[idx].intersection(setng[jj])
        bb = len(aa) / max(lg[idx],lg[jj])
        mylist.append(bb)
    return mylist

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    myres = pool.map(myfunc3, range(len(lines)-1))
    pool.close()
```

Comment: why do you think a numpy array will take less memory than a list?

Comment: @maxymoo Typically because Python numbers are objects while Numpy values are stored as C-style arrays (i.e. contiguous memory). For example, the size of an int in python is 24 bytes, while an int in Numpy/C might only be 8 bytes tops.

Comment: myres is a list of lists. This becomes expensive if there are too many combinations to compute. getsizeof from sys might help to check size. If scaled properly I think even a numpy.int8 which is 1 byte would do the work for me. Even with this scaling my final array will be ~ 2GB, then the symmetry matrix will be double this size.

Comment: does this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964809/numpy-vs-multiprocessing-and-mmap?rq=1

Comment: @maxymoo do I really need a memmapped array? I am guessing the solution requires a globally shared array, yet unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a self-solution, which is not the most efficient one, yet does the job done. I used ideas from a few related SO questions. The key here is **imap** which lowers the memory consumption and also running the code on Linux.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = len(lines)
    dma = np.zeros(m * (m - 1) // 2, dtype=np.int8)
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    idx = 0
    for resultset in pool.imap(myfunc3, range(len(lines)-1)):
        lenres = len(resultset)
        dma[idx:lenres+idx] = resultset
        idx += lenres
    pool.close()
```

This populates *dma* array as it was originally intended. I am sure this could be further improved by directly writing the result to the array in the function, rather than collecting results in a list.